# Using Tapjoy Adobe AIR sdk

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, tapjoy

I wish to use Tapjoy in my Adobe AIR iOS project. However I have no clue how to integrate it in my app. The documentation provided by them is very poor and difficult to understand. Following is what I have done till now :

1 . Added required ANE and swc to the project.
2. Added following imports in my code

```
import com.tapjoy.extensions.ITapjoyConnectRequestCallback;
import com.tapjoy.extensions.TapjoyAIR;
import com.tapjoy.extensions.TapjoyEvent;
import com.tapjoy.extensions.TapjoyMacAddressOption;
import com.tapjoy.extensions.TapjoyPointsEvent;
import com.tapjoy.extensions.TapjoyTransition;
import com.tapjoy.extensions.TapjoyViewChangedEvent;
import com.tapjoy.extensions.TJEvent;
import com.tapjoy.extensions.ITJEventCallback;
import com.tapjoy.extensions.TJEventRequest;
```

3. Inside Constructor checked for the Platform

   ```
   if (Capabilities.manufacturer.search("iOS") != -1)
       {
           // iOS platform
           // If you are not using Tapjoy Managed currency, you would set      your own user ID here.
           //  connectFlags["TJC_OPTION_USER_ID"] ="A_UNIQUE_USER_ID";

           // You can also set your event segmentation parameters here.
           //  var segmentationParams:Object = { "iap": true }
           //  connectFlags["TJC_OPTION_SEGMENTATION_PARAMS"] = segmentationParams;

           // Enable logging
           connectFlags["TJC_OPTION_ENABLE_LOGGING"] = true;

           // Pass option to toggle the collection of MAC address
           connectFlags["TJC_OPTION_COLLECT_MAC_ADDRESS"] = TapjoyMacAddressOption.MacAddressOptionOffWithVersionCheck;

           TapjoyAIR.requestTapjoyConnect("13b0ae6a-8516-4405-9dcf-fe4e526486b2", "XHdOwPa8de7p4aseeYP0", connectFlags); 
           //trace("" + connector);
       }
       else
       {
           // Android platform

           // If you are not using Tapjoy Managed currency, you would set your own user ID here.
           //  connectFlags["user_id"] ="A_UNIQUE_USER_ID";

           // You can also set your event segmentation parameters here.
           //  var segmentationParams:Object = { "iap": true }
           //  connectFlags["segmentation_params"] = segmentationParams;

           // Enable logging
           connectFlags["enable_logging"] = true;

           TapjoyAIR.requestTapjoyConnect("bba49f11-b87f-4c0f-9632-21aa810dd6f1", "yiQIURFEeKm0zbOggubu", connectFlags);
           //isAndroid = true;
       }
   ```
4. Next I need to show theOfferWall if connection to Tapjoy has succeded. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add listeners to the object (as defined in docs):

You must call requestTapjoyConnect before any other Tapjoy methods, ex:

```
TapjoyAIR.requestTapjoyConnect("YOUR_TAPJOY_APP_ID_HERE", "YOUR_TAPJOY_SECRET_KEY_HERE");

extension = TapjoyAIR.getTapjoyConnectInstance();
```

**Register an event listener for all the events you want to capture**, ex:

```
extension.addEventListener(type, function, …);
```

You can find all Tapjoy AIR events defined in `TapjoyEvent`, `TapjoyDisplayAdEvent` and `TapjoyPointsEvent`.

Comment: Thanks, but what I should do to check if the connection to Tapjoy was successful or not? I want to create a button on click of which i wish to show the offerWall.

Comment: As I said - just add event listener to see if the connection was ok. `TapjoyEvent` has such one: `TJ_CONNECT_SUCCESS`. Would be something like `extension.addEventListener(TapjoyEvent.TJ_CONNECT_SUCCESS, onConnectionSuccess);`

Comment: Thanks a ton. One more issue I have is that it works smooth on iOS, but does not work on Android. Do I have to add anything in the xml to make it work for android?

Comment: Buddy just check the manual: http://home.tapjoy.com/tech/product-overview/available-plugins/adobe-air-plugin Yes, it's said that you must modify the manifesto and you even got the code to insert!